# monaco editor set range text color programatically without css in style.css

Tags: monaco-editor

I am trying to use Monaco editor to create an application for simple text processing
(eg: select a range of text, change its foreground and background color).
Is there an easy way to do this? or even best, is there any best free opensource rich text like Grammarly, I just need some mark-down features with color.

This example uses a CSS class name, but not what I am looking for.
https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html#interacting-with-the-editor-line-and-inline-decorations
The CSS is predefined, not dynamically generated.

Thanks

Comment: Monaco Editor is a web component, something that's rendered into the DOM. How would you set styles without CSS?

Comment: @MikeLischke, I mean without CSS in the style file. If there is a way to dynamically generate CSS style, that is what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually my solution is still using `deltaDecorations` just like official playground examples.

But in practice, you can use sass iteration to speed up creating batch styles, below is my real project code, FYI:

```css
  $palette: (
    '30': rgba(0,0,0,1),
    '31': rgba(247,49,49,1),
    '32': rgba(127,202,84,1),
    '33': rgba(246,222,84,1),
    '34': rgba(0,0,255,1),
    '35': rgba(255,0,255,1),
    '36': rgba(0,255,255,1),
    '37': rgba(255,255,255,1),
    '90': rgba(128,128,128,1),
    '40': rgba(0,0,0,1),
    '41': rgba(247,49,49,1),
    '42': rgba(127,202,84,1),
    '43': rgba(246,222,84,1),
    '44': rgba(0,0,255,1),
    '45': rgba(255,0,255,1),
    '46': rgba(0,255,255,1),
    '47': rgba(255,255,255,1),
  );
  @each $key, $color in $palette {
    :deep(.monaco-color-#{$key}) {
      color: $color;
    }
  }
```